# How to pivot column values into columns?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

i've browsed through a lot of the SQL Pivot example on Stackoverflow, in the Books Online, and in google, and i still cannot figure out how to perform (what i would call) a simple pivot operation.

### [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020690/how-to-make-column-to-row-without-an-aggregate-function-in-sql-server-2005-8)

Sample data:

```
Name     Class       Score
=======  ==========  ======
Nick     Chinese     80 
Nick     English     70 
Nick     Biology     85 
Nick     Maths       85
Kent     Chinese     80 
Kent     Maths       90 
Kent     English     70 
Kent     Biology     85
```

### Desired output 1 - Pivot by Class, aggregate by Name

```
Name     Chinese     English   Biology  Maths
=======  ==========  ========  =======  ======
Nick     80          70        85       85
Kent     80          70        85       90
```

Note:

> In my head i imagine the syntax would be:
>
> ```
> SELECT Score FROM Scores
> GROUP BY Name
> PIVOT BY Class
> ```

### Desired output 2 - Pivot by Class, aggregate Score

```
Name     Chinese     English   Biology  Maths
=======  ==========  ========  =======  ======
70                   Nick
70                   Kent
80       Nick        
80       Kent             
85                             Nick     Nick
85                             Kent
90                                      Kent
```

Note:

> In my head i imagine the syntax would be:
>
> ```
> SELECT Name FROM Scores
> GROUP BY Score
> PIVOT BY Class
> ```

### Desired output 3 - Pivot by Score, aggregate by Name

```
Name     70          80        85       90
=======  ==========  ========  =======  =====
Nick     English     Chinese   Biology  
Nick     English     Chinese   Maths
Kent     English     Chinese   Biology  Maths
```

Note:

> In my head i imagine the syntax would be:
>
> ```
> SELECT Class FROM Scores
> GROUP BY Name
> PIVOT BY Score
> ```

### Desired output 4 - Pivot by Score, aggregate by Class

```
Class    70          80        85       90
=======  ==========  ========  =======  =====
Chinese              Nick
Chinese              Kent
English  Nick
English  Kent
Biology                        Nick
Biology                        Kent
Maths                          Nick     Kent
```

> In my head i imagine the syntax would be:
>
> ```
> SELECT Name FROM Scores
> GROUP BY Class 
> PIVOT BY Score
> ```

### Desired output 5 - Pivot by Name, aggregate by Class

```
Class    Nick  Kent
=======  ====  ====
Chinese  80    80
English  70    70
Biology  85    85
Maths    85    90
```

> In my head i imagine the syntax would be:
>
> ```
> SELECT Score FROM Scores
> GROUP BY Class
> PIVOT BY Name
> ```

### Desired output 6 - Pivot by Name, aggregate by Score

```
Score  Nick     Kent
=====  =======  =======
70     English  English
80     Chinese  Chinese
85     Biology  Biology
85     Maths    Biology
90              Maths
```

> In my head i imagine the syntax would be:
>
> ```
> SELECT Class FROM Scores
> GROUP BY Score
> PIVOT BY Name
> ```

**Note:** i don't want a *single* query that can perform all these pivots. i am using the sample data, and sample pivots, so use as examples of what pivots i might want to perform.

### **Another Example Set**

Another example might be parsing a log of user's logging into the domain:

```
LoginDate          Username  MachineName
=================  ========  ===========
20120901 8:49:22   iboyd     obsidian
20120901 9:10:19   nbach     president
20120901 13:07:18  nback     nichpc
20120902 8:58:38   iboyd     obsidian
20120202 9:14:44   nbach     president
20120902 18:34:43  iboyd     harpax
20120903 8:57:13   iboyd     obsidian
20120904 20:03:55  iboyd     harpax
```

### Desired output 7 - Pivot by date portion of LoginDate, aggregate by Username:

```
Username  20120901   20120902  20120903  20120914
========  =========  ========  ========  ========
iboyd     obsidian   obsidian  obsidian  harpax
iboyd     obsidian   harpax    obsidian  harpax
nbach     president  president
nback     nichpc     president
```

> In my head i imagine the syntax would be:
>
> ```
> SELECT MachineName FROM Logins
> GROUP BY Username
> PIVOT BY CONVERT(varchar(50), LoginDate, 112) --yyyymmdd format
> ```
>
> Or perhaps:
>
> ```
> SELECT MachineName FROM Logins
> GROUP BY Username
> PIVOT BY CAST(LoginDate AS DATE)
> ```

i just can't seem to wrap my head out the `PIVOT` syntax; in order to tell SQL Server what column values should become columns, and what column values the aggregation happens over.

Everyone seems to want to hard-code the columns, or invokes some XML queries. i just want to do a pivot!

---

### See also

- [Pivot SQL query - Show Date in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546433/pivot-sql-query-show-date-in-column)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pivot+sql-server
- [How to Pivot a Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857752/how-to-pivot-a-table)
- [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f4a1/3)

---

### The Real Question<sup>TM</sup>

The real problem i'm trying to solve today is the screenshot mockup that was given to me by the *"business"*:

[image]

Which could be a fairly obvious query to write, if the SQL Server syntax were fairly obvious to me:

```
SELECT 
    JobName, ShiftName, 
    Firstname+' '+Lastname+' - '+BankCode
FROM Transactions
GROUP BY JobName, ShiftName
PIVOT BY TransactionDate
```

Comment: `PIVOT` does not auto create columns based upon your existing data. The column names are always static in a `PIVOT` statement (though of course you can generate the query dynamically based off the values that exist in your data). If you search for "dynamic pivot" you should find some example code.

Comment: Good discussion of pivot found here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083079/t-sql-select-query-to-return-combined-result-of-multiple-tables/12083697#12083697

Also has an answer I provided which shows one of several methods for creating a dynamic pivot that will work with any practical number of columns.

Answer (score 4):

Think of the pivot operator as replacing your group by. Here is an example for your sample #1 and 3:

```
SELECT name, [Chinese], [English], [Biology], [Maths]
FROM scores s
PIVOT (
    SUM(score) 
    FOR Class IN ([Chinese], [English], [Biology], [Maths])
) p

SELECT name, [70], [80], [85], [90]
FROM scores s
PIVOT (
    MAX(class) 
    FOR score IN ([70], [80], [85], [90])
) p
```